# How can I deserialize JSON with a top-level array using Serde?

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, serde

I have a some JSON data that is returned from a web service. The JSON is a top-level array:

```
[
    {
        "data": "value1"
    },
    {
        "data": "value2"
    },
    {
        "data": "value3"
    }
]
```

Using `serde_derive` to make `struct`s I can can deserialize the data contained within the array, however, I am unable to get Serde to deserialize the top-level array.

Am I missing something, or can Serde not deserialize top level-arrays?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can simply use a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html):

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    data: String,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), serde_json::Error> {
    let data = r#"[
        {
            "data": "value1"
        },
        {
            "data": "value2"
        },
        {
            "data": "value3"
        }
    ]"#;

    let datas: Vec<Foo> = serde_json::from_str(data)?;

    for data in datas.iter() {
        println!("{:#?}", data);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

---

If you wish, you could also use [transparent](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#transparent):

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(transparent)]
struct Foos {
    foos: Vec<Foo>,
}

let foos: Foos = serde_json::from_str(data)?;
```

This allows to encapsulate your data with your type.

Comment: What if the input JSON body is not an array? Is there any general way to handle it? Thansk!

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin there is no more simple https://github.com/serde-rs/json#parsing-json-as-strongly-typed-data-structures

Comment: Thank you, I just find the the answer in issue discussion, We can use `let foos: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(data)?;`

Comment: But how do you parse this file efficiently if it's 10 GB size ?