# Serde Stream Deserializer for a type other than serde_json::Value

Tags: json, rust, serde-json

I want to parse a JSON string of the form

```
{
    "a": {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    "b": {
        "foo": "baz"
    }
}
```

That is, at the top level there are a number of JSON objects separated by commas.
Each of these objects have the same fields as the others (i.e., I can easily represent all of these objects with a single `struct`).

Since there are several of these objects in the JSON string, I believe I should be using a `serde_json::StreamDeserializer`, though I am relatively new to Rust and `serde` in particular, so if this is not the right approach, please point me in the correct direction.

This code represents what I *want* to do:

```rust
use serde_json::Deserializer;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Data {
    foo: String,
}

fn main() {
    let data = r#"{
        "a": {"foo": "bar"},
        "b": {"foo": "baz"}
    }"#;

    let stream = Deserializer::from_str(data).into_iter::<Data>();

    for value in stream {
        println!("{:?}", value.unwrap());
    }
}
```

I would expect this code to produce some output similar to `Object({"a": Object({"foo": String("bar")}), "b": Object({"foo": String("baz")})})`.

This is the output I see if I change `Deserializer::from_str(data).into_iter::<Data>();` to `Deserializer::from_str(data).into_iter::<serde_json::Value>();`.

Instead, the code fails to compile, giving the error `Error("missing field 'foo'", line: 4, column: 5)`

So, what do I need to do in order to deserialize the JSON into `Data` structs rather than `Value`?

Comment: same thing than https://stackoverflow.com/q/44610594/7076153, you could make your question more generic this would be a great duplicate to use for future question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was much simpler than I thought. [Credit to /u/sfackler on Reddit for pointing this out to me](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/do5xkr/hey_rustaceans_got_an_easy_question_ask_here/f5v72r7?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

In this scenario, I don't need to use a `StreamDeserializer`; instead, I can just parse the JSON into a `HashMap` and extract the values I want from it.

For example:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Data {
    foo: String,
}

fn main() {
    let data = r#"{
        "a": {"foo": "bar"},
        "b": {"foo": "baz"}
    }"#;

    let m: HashMap<String, Data> = serde_json::from_str(&data).unwrap();
    for (_key, val) in m {
        println!("{:?}", val);
    }
}
```