# Deserialize json array of arrays and strings

Tags: json, vector, rust, deserialization, serde

I have json from a vendor api that looks like this:

```
[
    "Crappy vendor unwanted string",
    [
        {
            "key": "val",
            "...": "lots more",
        },
        {
            "it": "goes on",
        }
    ]
]
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do here. Simply passing this as a vec to serde ala [How to Deserialize a top level array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610594/how-can-i-deserialize-json-with-a-top-level-array-using-serde) doesn't work, as I don't know how to reference/pass the inner string and array to other structs.

I *can* simply do this:

```
    let json_string: String = res.text().await?;
```

however, that json string is unwieldy and unformatted. Not ideal.

Taking it a step further, I've created the following, which gets me close, but doesn't seem to work:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Outer {
   pub outer_tite: String,
   pub inner_vec: Vec<Inner>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Inner {
    pub inner_obj: InnerObj,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct InnerObj {
    pub key1: String,
    pub key2: String,
    ...
}

impl Outer {
    pub async fn get(...) -> Result<Vec<Outer>, ExitFailure> {
        let out: Vec<Outer> = rec.json::<Vec<Outer>>().await?;
        ok(out)
    }
}
```

The result here is that the first string encountered throws an error:

```
value: error decoding response body: invalid type: string "Bad vendor string", expected struct Outer at line 2...
```

Changing the input json is not an option, as it's a vendor endpoint.

I've tried the suggestions from [How can I deserialize JSON with a top-level array using Serde?]([How can I deserialize JSON with a top-level array using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610594/how-can-i-deserialize-json-with-a-top-level-array-using-serde)) - this does not work for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly deserialize a struct from a list of elements. The struct fields are deserialized in order. Your example code does not work since you only have one `Outer` element, containing multiple `InnerObj`. The `Inner` struct you added does not match the JSON structure you have shown.

The snippet shows how you can directly deserialize into the `Outer` struct, which contains the `String` and the `Vec`.

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Outer {
   pub outer_titel: String,
   pub inner_vec: Vec<Inner>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Inner {
    pub key1: String,
    pub key2: String,
}

#[test]
fn deser() {
    let j = r#"[
    "Crappy vendor unwanted string",
    [
        {
            "key1": "val1",
            "key2": "val2"
        },
        {
            "key1": "val1",
            "key2": "val2"
        }
    ]
]"#;
    let outer: Outer = serde_json::from_str(j).unwrap();
    assert_eq!("Crappy vendor unwanted string", outer.outer_titel);
    assert_eq!(2, outer.inner_vec.len());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8680fc2ba33ef2c8992197ada5696d14)